# What are the steps to put an application onto an iphone for testing?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a developer account that I would love to put to use but I can't figure out how to get my app onto my phone and all the documentation I'm finding is really jargony and confusing.

I created an archive that I can see in the organizer.

I also added my phone in the organizer.

but how do I unite the two things?!?!
maybe there is a good guide for this and I just don't know what to search for?

Comment: Have you tried researching at all? That's always the first step. Don't use the documentation if its really jargony and confusing, I've seen dozens of tutorials from other websites. Here's a very good website when it comes to iOS http://www.raywenderlich.com/ :)

Comment: @nhgrif omg! holy camole! so easy!!!

Comment: @Shrink all I had to do was press play... not sure why I didn't figure that out... but some things about xcode are just kinda hidden. I will check out raywenderlich.com though too. Thanks!!

Comment: @nhgrif ...now that my question is answered here on stack overflow but only answered in the comments what should i do? ...I could answer it myself or delete it or you could answer it and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device is set up through your developer account, it's literally as simple as choosing your device in Xcode (rather than a simulator) and pushing the triangle play button. You don't need to archive your app.